# Как посмотреть страницы посещения в Google Analitics

Tags: google-analytics

Поставил на сайт аналитику от Гугла, там есть такое отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если активный пользователь отвалится, то информация об активной странице тоже исчезнет, а мне бы хотелось просмотреть всю её накопленную, если это вообще можно.
Вот и интересуюсь: где её найти? Если в каких-то отчетах, то по каким фильтрам?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял то данную статистику можно найти во вкладке

АУДИТОРИЯ -> ПУТИ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕЙ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]